# incorporating a line of objC in C++ header

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am using the Syphon framework to serve video frames to a client. There is one line of code I need to use to serve the frames through the server, and I am stuck trying to write it into my c++ code.

The Syphon documentation [here](http://syphon.v002.info/FrameworkDocumentation/) gives this example:

```
[myServer publishFrameTexture:myTex textureTarget:GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT imageRegion:NSMakeRect(0, 0, width, height) textureDimensions:NSMakeSize(width, height) flipped:NO];
```

How do I incorporate this into my c++ header? I have set my xcode compiler flags so that "Other C Flags" are set to "-x objective-c" and "Other C++ Flags" to "-x objective-c++".

To give some context the rest of my code currently looks like this (and it builds):

```
class OpencvMat2Syphon {

    // hack to call glut to create opengl context (one only so they don't wipe out each other)
    static bool haveGLContext;
    uint texId;
    CGLContextObj ctx;
    static SyphonServer *syphonServer;

public:

    OpencvMat2Syphon() {

        if (!haveGLContext) {
            char* str[1];  // glut hack for faking passing CLI parameters from main
            int argc = 1;
            str[0] = "app";
            glutInit(&argc, str);
            glutCreateWindow("imageGrabber");
            glutDisplayFunc([]{});
            glutHideWindow();
            haveGLContext = true;
        }

        ctx = CGLGetCurrentContext();
        std::cout << "cgl context: " << ctx << std::endl;
        SyphonServer *syphonServer = [[SyphonServer alloc] initWithName:@"imageGrabberOutput" context:ctx options:nil];

        glGenTextures(1, &texId);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
        glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE );
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
    }

    ~OpencvMat2Syphon() {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &texId);
    }

    uint getTexId() {
        return texId;
    }

    void uploadTexture(cv::Mat mat) {

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
        // can do swizzling/channel-flipping here? see https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8, mat.cols, mat.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mat.data);


// ??            [syphonServer publishFrameTexture:texId textureTarget:GL_TEXTURE_2D imageRegion:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1280, 720) textureDimensions:NSMakeSize(1280, 720) flipped:NO];

    }
};

bool OpencvMat2Syphon::haveGLContext = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to factor that out? A very simple approach would be:

- write a function with an ordinary C signature that performs the `syphonServer` call;
- put the declaration of that function into an ordinary C header file;
- put the implementation of that function into an Objective-C file that includes the header;
- call the C function from your C++ class.

If you can rename the file that includes the header to .mm then that would also achieve the desired result in persuading the compiler to treat your file (and, by extension, its header) as Objective-C++.